# ActionMailer working fine in terminal, not sending to gmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I'm just about in the finishing stages of my website, however I am having trouble with the ActionMailer. It prints out the message just fine, I'm just eager to know how to wire it so it can send to gmail account. I'm primary confused how to route it and configure it properly.  I have a contact page that has a model that takes parameters like the recipient, subject, message and the time it was sent: **Mailer model:** *Note all this code is on a local machine*

```
class UserEmail < ActionMailer::Base

 default from: 'XXX@gmail.com'


 def contact(sender, subject, message, sent_at = Time.now)
@sender = sender
@message = message
@sent_at = sent_at.strftime("%B %e, %Y at %H:%M")
mail(:subject => subject)



 end



end
```

Here's the **about** controller which the **contact** methods lie in:

```
class AboutController < ApplicationController
# ...\controllers\home_controller.rb
#----------------------------------------------------
# show contact form

def contact
@title = "Contact"
@sender = ''
@subject = ''
@message = ''
end

def sendmail
@sender = params[:sender]
@subject = params[:subject]
@message = params[:message]
if validate(@sender, @subject, @message)
  UserEmail.contact(@sender, @subject, @message).deliver      
  flash[:success] = "Your message sent sucessfully!"      
  redirect_to about_index_path
else

  flash.now[:error] = "Your message did not send"     

  redirect_to about_index_path
end
end

private
def validate(sender, subject, message)
  @email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  if sender.blank? || subject.blank? || message.blank?
    @error = "Message not sent: Required information not filled"
    return false
  elsif subject.length >= 50
    @error = "Message not sent: Subject must be smaller than 50 characters"
    return false
elsif sender[@email_regex].nil?
    @error = "Message not sent: Email not valid"
    return false
  else
    return true
  end
end
end
```

Now this is where I am ***lost***. 
Here's what my route like to the mailer. Is this routed appropriately?:

```
 match '/contact_email', :to => 'about#sendmail'
```

When I configure the mailer, does the code rest in the application.rb or the development.rb? Here's what I have in my **application.rb**:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true 
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp 
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address            => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port               => 587,
    :user_name          => 'XXX@gmail.com',
    :password           => 'XXX',
    :authentication     => 'plain',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
def contact(sender, subject, message, sent_at = Time.now)
  @sender = sender
  @message = message
  @sent_at = sent_at.strftime("%B %e, %Y at %H:%M")
  mail(:subject => subject)
end
```

to

```
def contact(sender, subject, message, recipient, sent_at = Time.now)
  @sender = sender
  @message = message
  @sent_at = sent_at.strftime("%B %e, %Y at %H:%M")
  @recipient = recipient

  mail(:subject => subject, :to => @recipient)
end
```

And don't forget to set recipient in your calling function.

Answer (score 0):

Have you put the following lines in development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true 
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

Comment: Just did what you said. Looks like it's breaking on line 18 on the UserEmail instance within the about controller. This is the error message I get:  At least one recipient (To, Cc or Bcc) is required to send a message

Comment: In your UserEmail, you have to define the recipient.take a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html

Comment: Thanks for the help, mcGar. I wish I can vote you up but still working on getting my rep up!